# Кружево - росіянізм чи літературне слово?

Tags: етимологія, іменники, росіянізм

Знайшла у творі Марко Вовчок ["Маша"](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/styslo/printit.php?tid=10459) таке речення:

> У сім років вона захотіла навчитися плести **кружево**, над роботою сиділа цілий тиждень поки не навчилася ідеально плести.

Отож цікавить, чи слово "***кружево***" - це літературне чи таки росіянізм?

У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/kruzhevo) цього слова немає, однак є "мереживо".

Comment: Тут мені, наприклад, також більше подобається відповідь пана @muffin, вона дає повне розуміння того, звідки прийшло слово, а не того, в якій ще мові є таке слово.  Також, будь ласка, подумайте, яка відповідь вам подобається найбільше. Дуже вдячний вам за внесок у сайт, але прошу уважно поставитися до останніх коментарів. Ми перш за все хочемо допомогти зробити хороші запитання і відповіді, але є поведінка, яка не дуже заохочується і може почати викликати підозри.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Звернувшись до [Етимологічного словника української мови](http://resource.history.org.ua/cgi-bin/eiu/history.exe?&I21DBN=ELIB&P21DBN=ELIB&S21STN=1&S21REF=10&S21FMT=elib_all&C21COM=S&S21CNR=20&S21P01=0&S21P02=0&S21P03=ID=&S21COLORTERMS=0&S21STR=0007831), бачимо, що це слово запозичене з російської мови. З цього випливає, що "*кружево*" - росіянізм.

[image: кружево]